# Double-click vs two single clicks

Tags: javascript, browser

How does browser recognize two single `click` events vs  `dblclick`? I am thinking this has something to do with the duration between click events but I am not finding any documentation for it. I checked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: You can set the speed of it in your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't detect double click vs. single clicks. These are two different events that the browser receives. This is usually configurable in your OS. In other words, as a website developer, you have no control over this delay.